# theorem Let A be a set. Then ∪P(A)=A

Tags: elementary-set-theory

prove this theorem. Let A be a set. Then ∪P(A)=A.

I've tried to do a similar problem but I am unsure how to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What is ∪P(A)?

Comment: @Bernard: The union over all the sets in the power set of $A$. I.e. the union of all the subsets of $A$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the choice of tags? Why is this a philosophy question?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the definitions to show that $\bigcup\wp(A)\subseteq A$ and $A\subseteq\bigcup\wp(A)$. I’ll start the first one for you to get you started. Let $x\in\bigcup\wp(A)$; then by the definition of union there is an $S\in\wp(A)$ such that $x\in S$. But then $x\in S\subseteq A$, so … ?